# Fourier transform of a continuous non-periodic function in matlab

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, signal-processing

I would like to use matlab to find an Fourier transfom of a function which is known only on a grid.

As an example I take the function f(x) = exp (-x^2), which Fourier transform is known and is equal to g(y) = pi^(1/2)*exp(-y^2/4);

For the fourier transform in matlab I use fft() and apparently I am doing something wrong because the result is weird.

x = -10:0.01:10;
y = exp(-x.^2);
plot(x, fft(y));

[image: fft(y)]

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong except that the variable `x` is not the appropriate variable to plot the spectrum, but this does not matter much here. The problem is that your function only has components at very low frequencies which you hardly see in your full-range plot. If you swap the right and the left half of the spectrum and plot just the range around zero frequency you see what you would expect to see:

```
Y1=[Y(1952:2001),Y(1:50)];
plot(abs(Y1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Matt L. It looks pretty much like what was expected. Could you please explain why it is scaled by the factor 100 and why do you take the first and the last 50 components of Y1 and swap them? And where do 50 and 100 come from?

Comment: @veryveryanonym: The scaling comes from your sample interval $T=0.01$. The spectrum of the sampled signal is scaled by $1/T$. The center of my plot is frequency zero. By swapping I can show the negative frequencies, so you get to see the complete Gaussian centered at frequency zero. The FFT gives you the frequencies in the interval $[0,f_s]$ ($f_s=1/T$). Due to the periodicity of the spectrum of the sampled signal, the FFT bins in the interval $[f_s/2,f_s]$ correspond to the negative frequencies. The 50 points to the left and right of $f=0$ are just chosen to zoom in on the Gaussian.